# save values for variables in a shell subprocess

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
while IFS=" " read token
do
  BUFFER="$BUFFER $token"
done < "$VAR"
```

I have a problem probably related to the fact that in the `sh` and `bash` shell `read` is being executed in a subprocess, so I can't find a correct way to save and "chain" the results of this `while` loop.

In short my `BUFFER` variable gets a reset at each cycle and I can't really think of a good portable way to make this work.

Comment: Hmm, works for me (as it should - BUFFER is always in scope inside and outside the while loop).  I assume the `$VAR` variable contains a filename - is that right?

Comment: **However** If you are piping from a command instead of redirecting from a file, then each side of the pipe is effectively in a subshell, so BUFFER would end up out of scope once the pipe is done

Comment: @DigitalTrauma `VAR` contains a series of filenames separated by newlines or whitespaces. I'm using `sh` and it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: With a simple `<` redirect, you can only redirect from one file at a time: `sh: 4: cannot open fileA fileB: No such file

Comment: Assuming your code did work, `BUFFER` and `VAR` would have essentially the same value anyway.

Comment: @chepner not true, `VAR` is a file name, `BUFFER` is a file content

Comment: I basically have to read from a list stored inside a variable and chain together the elements in that list using custom values for `IFS` in order to obtain a new list formatted as I would like it to be.

Comment: @BruceK doesn't look like it will work under the `sh`, what kind of expansion is that ?

Comment: This has a "bash" tag.  It is bash.  For Solaris /bin/sh:  BUFFER=`cat $VAR`  (backticks surround the "cat $VAR")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$VAR` is a list of filenames, I assume you need the files concatenated together, then redirected to the while loop.  I think something like the following should work in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
$ VAR="
/etc/networks
/etc/papersize
"
$ while IFS=" " read token; do
      BUFFER="$BUFFER $token"
  done < <( cat $VAR )
$
$ echo $BUFFER
# symbolic names for networks, see networks(5) for more information link-local 169.254.0.0 letter
$
```

Note the `<( )` [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)-specific, so probably won't work with [sh](/questions/tagged/sh).

---

Since you need something to work in [sh](/questions/tagged/sh), you can just put this the while loop in a for loop over all the filenames:

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR="
/etc/networks
/etc/papersize
"

for f in $VAR; do
    while IFS=" " read token; do
        BUFFER="$BUFFER $token"
    done < $f
done

echo $BUFFER
```

Comment: thanks, but the core of my problem really is high portability across at least this 2 shells, `bash` offers a lot of features that are not available under the `sh`.

Comment: @user2485710 See my edit with an additional `sh`-compatible solution.

Comment: thanks for your help, my script is getting too convoluted and hairy, I'll probably rewrite it, I also discovered some subtle problem with symbolic links and non "standard" files, apparently some unix/linux utilities like to follow symbolic links by default and this adds complexity and is one more reason for me to rethink this.